# Please evaluate my argument about incompleteness theorem and first cause

Tags: logic, metaphysics, causality, goedel

Here is my argument:

---

One of the incompleteness theorems is

“If a system is noncontradiction, it is incomplete”

Incomplete means that there are propositions that are true but cannot be proven.

The proposition is an axiom

Axiom is the first cause

the world is a system

in other words,

If there is no contradiction in the world, a first cause exists.

---

**Is this reasoning sound, and if so, how not?**

Comment: I see a lot of contradictions in the world. "*You never know what is enough, until you know what is more than enough.*" - William Blake

Comment: That’s not how Gödel’s theorems work. It is in regard to formalized systems with a rich enough grammar that sentences about themselves can be formulated. In Gödel’s proofs, the sentence-type he constructed are similar to a liar paradox: “this sentence is unprovable.” Nothing about God.

Comment: Where did you get that notion of Incompleteness from? A formal language  is Complete with respect to some Property P, under some Collection of Axioms if every φ ( formula) in the language can be proven to have Propery P or not have property P. In this case, the Property is truth. So We have incompleteness if not every φ in the language can be proven true or false, i.e. the truth value of φ is independent of the Axioms.

Comment: No first cause at all. Axioms are statements.

Comment: GIT applies to **formal** systems, not to metaphysical ones.

Comment: For example, The English Alphabet , is Complete with respect to the Property (is a word in the dictionary) because every collection of letters can be verified to either be a word in the dictionary, or not be a word. But, if we consider the property ( will never be a word in a future dictionary), then we have incompleteness, because it's impossible to prove a collection of letters will never be a word in some future Dictionary

Comment: "Incomplete means that there are propositions that are true but cannot be proven." - nah. It means there are propositions that can be neither proven nor disproven. Whether these propositions are "true" is a dubious question; by what means can we assign them truth? Only by applying another, larger system, perhaps even an informal one. But the larger system must also be incomplete or inconsistent. And different choices of "larger system" can make the propositions false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you are making an [analogical argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy), but it's a bad analogy. 'Causes' and 'axioms' are different categories of [ontological commitments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_commitment), and **therefore you are committing a [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake)**. (For more information on types in reasoning, see [simple type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).) To wit:

1. A '[cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality)' has a type of '[event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event)'. More specifically, a cause is an event that precedents a separate category of event called effect.
2. An '[axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom)' has a type of '[proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)'. More specifically, it is a proposition that is used as a premise or foundation in inference to arrive at a conclusion.

So, in both cases, we have one ontological entity that precedes another (cause:effect::axiom:conclusion), but to build such an analogy is a [false analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy#False_analogy) in reasoning about the wider metaphysical discourse trying to relate the universe and the incompleteness theorems because other than some general notion of precedence of antecedents over consequents in our ontology; **cause and effects are imputed to be characteristic of events in the physical world and axioms and conclusions are imputed to be characteristic of our mental reasoning. When you conflate the mental and the physical, you have textbook categorical error** in the way that Ryle outlined. From WP:

> A category mistake (or category error, categorical mistake, or mistake of category), is a semantic or ontological error in which things belonging to a particular category are presented as if they belong to a different category, or, alternatively, a property is ascribed to a thing that could not possibly have that property.

You conclude:

> If there is no **contradiction<sub>[mental]</sub>** in the world, a first **cause<sub>[physical]</sub>** exists. (emphasis and subscript mine)

Your antecedent in this conditional statement deals with contradiction which is a [truth-semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics) concept related to reasoning and is in the mental category, and consequent in this statement is declaring that a cause, which is an event in the physical category exists. **You are mixing apples and oranges.**